# Infinite elements in a div (scroll right)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a problem with a div that i want to put a lot of images in.

But when the images reach the limit of the div the new images go in a new line, not in the same line.

What i want:

```
<div>-------------------------------------------------- n</div>
```

scrollbar right-left

What i get:

```
<div>--------------------------
------------------------ n</div>
```

scrollbar top-down

Actually the div css is that:

```
<style>

div {

                        text-align: center;

                        margin-left:auto;
                        margin-right:auto;
                        background-color:#FFF;
                        overflow-x: scroll;
                        overflow-y: hidden;

                        width: 900px;
                        height: 120px;

                        border: 0px;

                        padding: 0px;


                    }

</style>
```

Hope i explained myself and you can help me.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when there are images over the limit? They can't stay in line if the width can't expand. Set `min-width` maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/edm53/1/

The trick here is:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Comment: You should be able to apply scrolling using overflow-x: scroll;

Comment: I was going to suggest wrapping the images in another div, inside of the existing div, and give it position:absolute, but your solution works well :)